# Nginx Kept Throwing 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04

Nginx : nginx/1.11.2

I kept getting **502 Bad Gateway** even after I update my nginx config.

---

## Nginx Config

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k; <----
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;<----
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;<----
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;<----
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;<----
    }
```

---

I also did `service nginx reload` as well after modify and save the settings.

---

## Logs

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
2016/07/30 14:24:16 [notice] 18776#18776: signal process started
2016/07/30 16:46:39 [notice] 20193#20193: signal process started
2016/07/31 06:25:02 [emerg] 20196#20196: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2016/07/31 06:25:02 [emerg] 20196#20196: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2016/07/31 06:25:02 [emerg] 20196#20196: open() "/var/log/nginx/default-error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

---

**/var/log/nginx/access.log**

```
64.16.214.100 - - [30/Jul/2016:20:04:30 -0400] "GET /myadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.0" 404 169 "-" "-"
192.227.209.147 - - [30/Jul/2016:20:34:31 -0400] "GET /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:) HTTP/1.1" 400 173 "-" "-"
141.212.122.160 - - [31/Jul/2016:03:59:32 -0400] "GET /x HTTP/1.1" 400 173 "-" "Telesphoreo"
64.16.214.100 - - [31/Jul/2016:14:39:41 -0400] "GET /pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.0" 404 169 "-" "-"
213.128.81.66 - - [01/Aug/2016:12:13:26 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 169 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"
```

**/var/log/nginx/default-error.log**

```
2016/08/02 11:52:48 [error] 2894#2894: *7 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 72.22.171.98, server: default, request: "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "104.236.15.216", referrer: "http://104.236.15.216/sign-in"
2016/08/02 11:54:08 [error] 2894#2894: *7 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 72.22.171.98, server: default, request: "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "104.236.15.216", referrer: "http://104.236.15.216/sign-in"
2016/08/02 12:02:28 [error] 2893#2893: *17 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 72.22.171.98, server: default, request: "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "104.236.15.216", referrer: "http://104.236.15.216/sign-in"
2016/08/02 12:03:28 [error] 2893#2893: *20 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 72.22.171.98, server: default, request: "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "104.236.15.216", referrer: "http://104.236.15.216/sign-in"
2016/08/02 12:25:28 [error] 2893#2893: *28 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 72.22.171.98, server: default, request: "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "104.236.15.216"
```

---

Did I missed anything else ?

Do I need to anything to my `php.ini` settings ?

Any hints / suggestions will mean a lot to me !

Comment: does `/var/log/nginx/error.log` have any extra info?

Comment: I updated my post. I got something now after refresh.

Comment: do you have php7-fpm installed as a service? `service php7-fpm status` (or check `/etc/init.d/`, might be called somethingn else)? does that sock file exist (`ls /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`)?

Comment: I don't think I have `php7-fpm` installed as service. Should I install it ?

Comment: Yep. [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04) kind of outlines the steps. You'll need to install the PPA at the top and then install the `php7-fpm` service.